# Connect to RabbitMQ without providing username and password in Application properties in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I have created a spring boot application and have connected to a RabbitMqlServer.I have provided the username and password in the application.properties like so:

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5673
spring.rabbitmq.username=password
spring.rabbitmq.password=password

javainuse.rabbitmq.exchange=exchange
javainuse.rabbitmq.queue=queue
javainuse.rabbitmq.routingkey=routingkey
```

But the requirement is to do this without specifying the password in application.properties.

I tried the docs,but they were talking about virtual hosts and users,which I didn't understand.
Here is the link: https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html#seeding

I am new to Spring boot and RabbitMq, any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to look into how Spring loads properties instead, your requirements are not in `application.properties` but can you use the command line or environment to store them?  All seeding does is CONFIGURE rabbit with logins, not provide a way to access the service without one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mention the username/password from the code while reading them from some secrets files this is how you do it:

```
@Bean
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setUsername(YOUR_USERNAME);
    connectionFactory.setPassword(YOUR_PASSWORD);
    connectionFactory.setHost(YOUR_HOST);
    connectionFactory.setPort(YOUR_PORT);
    return connectionFactory;
}

@Bean
RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate();
    rabbitTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    return rabbitTemplate;
}
```

Now you can use your RabbitTemplate with the credentials provided while provided while building ConnectionFactory.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, your task is to connect to RabbitMQ with password but this password should not be specified in `application.properties` file.

In this case you can specify it, for example, through the environment variable `SPRING_RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=<your password>`:

```
$ export SPRING_RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=<password>
$ java -jar my-rabbitmq-app.jar

# Or
$ SPRING_RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=<password> java -jar my-rabbitmq-app.jar
```

Spring boot provides multiple ways of application configuration, so you may want to take a look at the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config